# Mifare Classic - Unknown Command

Tags: nfc, mifare

I'm simulating a Mifare Classic (1K) tag, and following the o ISO/IEC 14443 Type A protocol.

I could not found any information about what should be a proper response in case of receiving an unknown command from the reader (the reader supports other protocols).

Should I respond with an invalid operation NAK? Should I just ignore the command?

Answer (score 0):

[Mifare Classic EV1 datasheet](http://cache.nxp.com/documents/data_sheet/MF1S50YYX_V1.pdf) §9.3 suggests *Invalid operations* should return `4h` as response. It's quite unclear to me wether undefined commmands should be considered *Invalid operations*. I don't have a MFC EV1 at hand to test on. In my experience older MFCs simply do not answer to erroneous commands, though.